# MiniMax algorithm in Tic-Tac-Toe game

Tags: c, algorithm, tic-tac-toe, minimax

I'm trying to implement MiniMax algorithm in Tic-Tac-Toe game written in C. I can't obtain the best possible move. Here's my code (functions only):
Reference: https://editor.p5js.org/codingtrain/sketches/0zyUhZdJD

```
int minimax(int gameBoard[3][3], int depth, int ifMaximizing){
  if(hasWinner(gameBoard)!=0){
    return hasWinner(gameBoard);
  }
  if(ifMaximizing==1){
    int bestScore=-99999;
    for(int i=0; i<3; i++){
      for(int j=0; j<3; j++){
        if (gameBoard[i][j]==EMPTY){
          gameBoard[i][j]=CROSS;
          int score=minimax(gameBoard, depth+1, 0);
          gameBoard[i][j]=EMPTY;
            if(score>bestScore){
              bestScore=score;
            }
          }
        }
      }
    return bestScore;
  }
  else{
    int bestScore=99999;
    for(int i=0; i<3; i++){
      for(int j=0; j<3; j++){
        if (gameBoard[i][j]==EMPTY){
          gameBoard[i][j]=CIRCLE;
          int score=minimax(gameBoard, depth+1, 1);
          gameBoard[i][j]=EMPTY;
          if(score<bestScore){
              bestScore=score;
          }
        }
      }
    }
    return bestScore;
  }
}
```

Comment: What do you mean you can't get the best possible move? Do you have a failure case? What's the simplest (i.e. least recursion) board you can give it that results in a bad move?

Comment: As of now you are only returning the value of the board.

Comment: the `minimax` algorithm fails to use the `depth` parameter!  The `minimax` algorithm fails to discard the (less desirable) solutions